# How to compare two HashSets?

Tags: c#

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string[] array1 = { "C:/folder/a.txt", "C:/folder/b.txt", "C:/folder/c.txt", "C:/folder/d.txt" };

   string[] array2 = { "D:/a.txt", "D:/b.txt", "D:/c.txt", "D:/d.txt" };

   var hash1 = new HashSet<string>(array1);

   var hash2 = new HashSet<string>(array2);

}
```

I want to compare `hash1` and `hash2`. If `a.txt` file exists on the `hash2` then remove `C:/folder/a.txt` from `hash1`. Can we do this without Iterate values ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I'm not wrong, then it should be this:

```
var result = array1.Where(a1 =>  //take only those items from array1, which
              !array2.Any(     //have no such item in array2 
                a2 => a2.Contains(  //that contains
                   a1.Substring(a1.LastIndexOf("/"))))); //a similar filename

var hash1 = new HashSet<string>(result);
var hash2 = new HashSet<string>(array2);
```

That is, it would be enough to create `HashSet` with the necessary values already. So all the calculations are done over arrays.